# Copy and update 10000 MySQL rows / CPU usage

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cpu

I have a PHP script that:

- Copies new rows from the table "new" to "active" and delete the existing ones in "new".
- Update the existing data and delete the ones in "new", if there is already a row with the same id_measurement in "active"

My current solution uses Laravel Eloquent. The problem is that the MySQL CPU usage is very high (90-100% on Mac) with over 10000 rows each time. Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe just with SQL?

Edit:
Everything is working fine now, expect the update part:

```
        UPDATE foo_new as new
        JOIN foo_active as active
        ON active.id_bar = new.id_bar
        SET active.blah=new.blah,
            active.time_left=new.time_left
```

It's still really slow and uses a lot of the CPU.

Edit 2:
The solution are indexes. :)

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your code?

Comment: I have this thing, but it doesn't work very well. Do you think it can work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you bring it on application layer? delete and update the table using the power of mysql
I have done something similar use it

1) Update the table1 with new values of table2 using join

```
UPDATE tab1
INNER JOIN tab2 ON (tab1.DnameId = tab2.DNDOMAIN_ID)
SET 
tab1.col = tab2.col;
```

2) For deletion - delete all the rows from table1  which are not in table2

```
delete from   tab1 where tab1 .id not in (
select  id from tab2
)
```

Comment: Option 2 is probably faster than whatever it is that the OP is currently doing, but it is not a good (as in performative) solution!

Comment: @Strawberry may i know how? I know it updates all the rows, even those that are now updated, but that is better than fetching all the rows, comparing then on the application layer and then again updating the rows in case where update is required..

Comment: The "IN (SELECT)" method is just not very efficient

Comment: Thanks. Everything expect the update part is working now. I have made an edit.

Comment: @Danyal Yes, but the update one is still really slow.

Comment: Unfortunately when you're dealing with updates (one of the slowest functions in SQL) against huge numbers of fields (in this case an entire table) there's only so much you can do.  I'd start looking to see if a redesign of the application isn't in order, because if this table grows much more, it's going to go from just slow to eventually unusable.

Comment: Yeah, I just needed an index.